# What is wrong with this SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, left-join

I'm sure this is something really simple that I'm overlooking, but MS SQL is new to me -- I am (or at least thought I was) fairly comfortable with basic MySql though.

```
SELECT l.link_id, l.link_allcount, d.desc_id, d.desc_count, d.desc_text, h.hour_17,   dl.day_19 
FROM lnktrk_links AS l, lnktrk_hourly AS h, lnktrk_daily AS dl 
LEFT JOIN lnktrk_descriptions AS d ON l.link_id = d.link_id 
WHERE l.link_id = h.link_id AND l.link_id = dl.link_id AND l.link_is_click = 1
```

The error I get is:

```
'The multi-part identifier "l.link_id" could not be bound.
```

However l.link_id definitely exists. The following query without the join works as expected:

```
SELECT l.link_id, l.link_allcount, d.desc_id, d.desc_count, d.desc_text, h.hour_17, dl.day_19 
FROM lnktrk_links AS l, lnktrk_hourly AS h, lnktrk_daily AS dl, lnktrk_descriptions AS d 
WHERE l.link_id = h.link_id AND l.link_id = dl.link_id AND d.link_id = l.link_id AND l.link_is_click = 1
```

Comment: Note that l.link_id is a primary key. (d.link_id is not).

Comment: Similar question answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206558/what-is-a-multi-part-identifier-and-why-cant-it-be-bound)

Comment: It is a very poor practice to use implicit joins and the problem you have here is one of the reasons why. This syntax has been outdated for 18 years, why are you still using it. Youo need to always use explicit joins. Explicit joins are easier to maintian and less likely to cause problems such as accidental cross joins. There is no excuse ever for using an implicit join, you gain nothing from them and they are prone to errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is that the syntax binds

```
lnktrk_daily AS dl 
LEFT JOIN lnktrk_descriptions AS d 
    ON l.link_id = d.link_id
```

more tightly than the comma-separated clauses so you don't have an l in that part

What you have is grouped as:

```
SELECT l.link_id, l.link_allcount, d.desc_id, d.desc_count, d.desc_text, h.hour_17,   dl.day_19 
FROM lnktrk_links AS l, lnktrk_hourly AS h, 
( lnktrk_daily AS dl 
  LEFT JOIN lnktrk_descriptions AS d 
  ON l.link_id = d.link_id )
WHERE l.link_id = h.link_id AND l.link_id = dl.link_id AND l.link_is_click = 1
```

Comment: Yup, that's new to me. Moving the lnktrk_links AS l to the last comma-separated clause fixed it. 

To be honest I thought the "joining what to what" parameter was fully expressed in the "ON x=y" part of the JOIN clause? Is this different in MySql / MS SQL or have I just been unenlightened? I'm not sure how it makes sense that you can express the "ON x=y" and it not be fully qualified how the join will work.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
SELECT 
l.link_id, 
l.link_allcount, 
d.desc_id, 
d.desc_count, 
d.desc_text, 
h.hour_17,   
dl.day_19 

FROM lnktrk_links AS l
inner join lnktrk_hourly AS h
on l.link_id = h.link_id
inner join  lnktrk_daily AS dl
on l.link_id = dl.link_id 
LEFT JOIN lnktrk_descriptions AS d ON l.link_id = d.link_id 
WHERE   l.link_is_click = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

That `LEFT JOIN` is joining `lnktrk_daily AS dl` with `lnktrk_descriptions AS d` - neither of these are called `l`, so *in the context of that `JOIN`s `ON` clause*, `l` doesn't mean anything.

It looks like at the moment you are using the 'cross join plus `WHERE` clauses' style rather than 'inner joins with `ON` clauses' style. If you switch to the latter then `l` should have meaning across the whole `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You should join them all - instead of using FROM

Try this

```
SELECT l.link_id, l.link_allcount, d.desc_id, d.desc_count, d.desc_text, h.hour_17,   dl.day_19 
FROM lnktrk_links AS l
LEFT JOIN lnktrk_hourly AS h ON l.link_id = h.link_id
LEFT JOIN lnktrk_daily AS dl ON l.link_id = dl.link_id
LEFT JOIN lnktrk_descriptions AS d ON l.link_id = d.link_id 
WHERE l.link_is_click = 1
```

Comment: Don't foget to add an index for non primary keys that are used for join equals or where clauses!

Comment: Thanks. The other joins have a 1:1 relationship though -- it is only the descriptions that can have more than one for each link ID.

I could use INNER JOIN, but I thought From and Where x = y was synonymous with that ?

Comment: In theory yes - but a join should be faster and better optimized. You have more options in joins - see inner/outer,left/rigth joins.

A hint for joins is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419375/sql-join-differences