# How can I perform a JOIN on a JOIN-ed table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to perform a JOIN on a JOIN-ed table, and I'm not sure how to accomplish it. Hopefully, the query below demonstrates what I'm trying to do: get country names, each country's leader, and each leader's home town.

I think the problem with this query is using the JOIN-ed table "President" in the second join with President.HomeTown_Id. I don't know what else to try.

```
SELECT 
  Countries.Name AS Country, 
  President.Name AS Leader,
  PresidentHomeTown.Name AS LeaderHomeTown
FROM Countries
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PoliticalFigures AS President ON Countries.President_Id = President.Id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Cities AS PresidentHomeTown ON President.HomeTown_Id = PresidentHomeTown.Id
```

**In VS, I'm getting the error, "The multi-part identifier "President.Id" could not be bound."**

The names of tables and fields are fictitious, but I need to solve an identical problem. I changed the names to make things clearer; hopefully this will be relevant to more people.

-- update --

Maybe the original code helps:

```
SELECT 
    CaseComparisons.Directory AS CaseComparisonDir, 
    BaselineResult.Directory AS BaselineResultDir, 
    ComparisonResult.Directory AS ComparisonResultDir,
    Setup.FullSvnLink AS SvnLink,
    BaselineVersion.FullFilePath AS BaselineExecutableDir
FROM CaseComparisons 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Results AS BaselineResult ON CaseComparisons.BaselineResult_Id = Baseline.Id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Results AS ComparisonResult ON CaseComparisons.ComparisonResult_Id = Comparison.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Setups AS Setup ON Baseline.Setup_Id = Setups.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN BuildVersions AS BaselineVersion ON BaselineResult.Version_Id = BuildVersions.Id
WHERE 
    CaseComparisons.Status = 'Queued' OR 
    Baseline.Status = 'Queued' OR 
    Comparison.Status = 'Queued'
```

The errors I get when I run the query:

```
The multi-part identifier "Baseline.Id" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "Comparison.Id" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "Baseline.Setup_Id" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "Setups.Id" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "BuildVersions.Id" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "Baseline.Status" could not be bound.
```

Comment: Seems like you're on the right track? What's the issue you're having? Do you have sample data?

Comment: Your query should run just fine. Is it throwing an error?, or the data that retruns is not what you expected?

Comment: might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206558/what-is-a-multi-part-identifier-and-why-cant-it-be-bound.  Just to check does `president` table have a column `id`?

Comment: My "just curious" results from SO searches: 
"typo" -> 5,000+, 
"memory" -> 4,002, 
"loop" -> 3,919, 
"while" -> 3,159, 
"overflow" -> 2,670

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got mismatches between the aliases you're specifying (e.g. in `Results AS ComparisonResult`) and the aliases you're trying to use (e.g. in `Comparison.Id`). So, change this:

```
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Results AS ComparisonResult
                 ON CaseComparisons.ComparisonResult_Id = Comparison.Id
```

to either this:

```
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Results AS ComparisonResult
                 ON CaseComparisons.ComparisonResult_Id = ComparisonResult.Id
```

or this:

```
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Results AS Comparison
                 ON CaseComparisons.ComparisonResult_Id = Comparison.Id
```

(and similarly for all the other joins).

Comment: Thanks, that does it. Just a typo, huh? Embarrassing! I'll check this as the answer as soon as I can. (2 minutes remaining)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an Id column in President table. Double-check that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you have your names different:

```
SELECT 
    CaseComparisons.Directory AS CaseComparisonDir, 
    BaselineResult.Directory AS BaselineResultDir, 
    ComparisonResult.Directory AS ComparisonResultDir,
    Setup.FullSvnLink AS SvnLink,
    BaselineVersion.FullFilePath AS BaselineExecutableDir
FROM CaseComparisons 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Results AS BaselineResult ON CaseComparisons.BaselineResult_Id = BaselineResult.Id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Results AS ComparisonResult ON CaseComparisons.ComparisonResult_Id = ComparisonResult.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Setups AS Setup ON BaselineResult.Setup_Id = Setup.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN BuildVersions AS BaselineVersion ON BaselineResult.Version_Id = BaselineVersion.Id
WHERE 
    CaseComparisons.Status = 'Queued' OR 
    BaselineResult.Status = 'Queued' OR 
    ComparisonResult.Status = 'Queued'
```