# joining to tables in a query for ASP.NET C# ~ multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, grouping

Among other answers I have looked at the following:

[The multi-part identifier could not be bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314134/the-multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound)

However tying to use that answer I was still not able to make my grouping work.

The following query works:

```
string query = @"SELECT     
    ud.FirstName, 
    ud.LastName, 
    p.Name AS Product, 
    p.ItemNumber, 
    sc.AmountPurchased * sc.Price AS Total, 
    sc.DatePurchased,
    sc.IsInCart AS [NotShipped]
FROM         
    ShoppingCarts sc INNER JOIN
    UserDetails ud ON sc.ClientID = ud.Guid Left     
OUTER JOIN
    Products p ON sc.ProductID = p.ProductsId

WHERE sc.DatePurchased >= @date1
AND   sc.DatePurchased <= @date2  
AND   sc.IsInCart = @shipped ";
```

but when I try to group it like this:

```
string query = @"SELECT ud.LastName, sc.DatePurchased, SUM(Total)
    FROM(
SELECT     
    ud.FirstName, 
    ud.LastName, 
    p.Name AS Product, 
    p.ItemNumber, 
    sc.AmountPurchased * sc.Price AS Total, 
    sc.DatePurchased,
    sc.IsInCart AS [NotShipped]
FROM         
    ShoppingCarts sc INNER JOIN
    UserDetails ud ON sc.ClientID = ud.Guid Left     
OUTER JOIN
    Products p ON sc.ProductID = p.ProductsId
WHERE sc.DatePurchased >= @date1
AND   sc.DatePurchased <= @date2  
AND   sc.IsInCart = @shipped 
) AS result
GROUP BY ud.LastName, sc.DatePurchased";
```

I get the "multi-part identifier ud.LastName, etc cannot be bound"

Comment: The fields are no longer part of the aliased tables in the outer select. Just remove the `ud` and `sc` prefixes in the outer `select` and `group by`.

Comment: well, the error went away but now it's not giving me any data when I know there is data to return...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206558/what-is-a-multi-part-identifier-and-why-cant-it-be-bound
please refer this i think it will help you

Comment: Aakash, So are you saying I shouldn't be using aliases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing nested selects the aliases do not propagate out of their scope. This is more evident when looking at the equivalent [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) query (assuming you're using MS SQL Server / T-SQL):

```sql
;WITH
(
    SELECT     
        ud.FirstName, 
        ud.LastName, 
        p.Name AS Product, 
        p.ItemNumber, 
        sc.AmountPurchased * sc.Price AS Total, 
        sc.DatePurchased,
        sc.IsInCart AS [NotShipped]
    FROM         
        ShoppingCarts sc INNER JOIN
        UserDetails ud ON sc.ClientID = ud.Guid Left     
    OUTER JOIN
        Products p ON sc.ProductID = p.ProductsId
    WHERE sc.DatePurchased >= @date1
    AND   sc.DatePurchased <= @date2  
    AND   sc.IsInCart = @shipped
) AS Result
SELECT 
    LastName, 
    DatePurchased, 
    SUM(Total)
FROM Result
GROUP BY 
    LastName,
    DatePurchased
```

So your problem is solved by removing the `ud` and `sc` identifiers from the outer `select` and `group by`.

Comment: yes, I was using a MS SQL Server / T-SQL, thank you for this re-written query. When I look at it like that it makes so much more sense.