# SQL Dynamic Where and Group by

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, stored-procedures

I'm using stored procedure and linking it with ASP C#, the below query runs successfully with no errors:

```
SELECT       loginInfo.ApplicantID, Personal.FirstName, Personal.LastName, Personal.Nationality, Job.PositionType, 
                      Job.InterestedArea, loginInfo.ApplicantStatus, Latest.HighestDegree, Latest.CompletionDate, 
                      Latest.LatestJobTitle, Latest.LatestCompanyIndustry, Latest.StartDate, Latest.EndDate,
                      SUM(DATEDIFF(YEAR,Exper.StartDate,Exper.EndDate)) AS TotalYearsExp
FROM         dbo.ApplicantLoginInfo AS loginInfo INNER JOIN
                      dbo.PersonalInfo AS Personal ON loginInfo.ApplicantID = Personal.ApplicantID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.InterestedJob AS Job ON loginInfo.ApplicantID = Job.ApplicantID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.LatestAcadExpInfo AS Latest ON loginInfo.ApplicantID = Latest.ApplicantID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Experience AS Exper ON loginInfo.ApplicantID = Exper.ApplicantID

WHERE 1=1


GROUP BY loginInfo.ApplicantID, Personal.FirstName, Personal.LastName, Personal.Nationality, Job.PositionType, 
                      Job.InterestedArea, loginInfo.ApplicantStatus, Latest.HighestDegree, Latest.CompletionDate, 
                      Latest.LatestJobTitle, Latest.LatestCompanyIndustry, Latest.StartDate, Latest.EndDate

ORDER BY ApplicantID DESC
```

Now I need to add DYNAMIC where clauses, so I break the query into 3 parts @SQL,@WHERE,@GROUPBY.

Please note that I have a aggregate function sum.

```
    if @gender <> '' SET @WHERE = ' AND Gender='''+@gender+''''
    if @nationality <> '' SET @WHERE = @WHERE + ' AND Nationality='''+@nationality+''''
    if @highestdegree <> '' SET @WHERE = @WHERE + ' AND HighestDegree='''+@highestdegree+''''
    if @latestcompanyindustry <> '' SET @WHERE = @WHERE + ' AND LatestCompanyIndustry='''+@latestcompanyindustry+''''
    if @interestedarea <> '' SET @WHERE = @WHERE + ' AND InterestedArea='''+@interestedarea+''''

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT loginInfo.ApplicantID, Personal.FirstName, Personal.LastName, Personal.Nationality, Job.PositionType,
    Job.InterestedArea, loginInfo.ApplicantStatus, Latest.HighestDegree, Latest.CompletionDate, Latest.LatestJobTitle, Latest.LatestCompanyIndustry, Latest.StartDate, Latest.EndDate,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(YEAR,Exper.StartDate,Exper.EndDate)) AS TotalYearsExp
    FROM dbo.ApplicantLoginInfo AS loginInfo INNER JOIN dbo.PersonalInfo AS Personal ON loginInfo.ApplicantID = Personal.ApplicantID INNER JOIN
    dbo.InterestedJob AS Job ON loginInfo.ApplicantID = Job.ApplicantID INNER JOIN 
dbo.LatestAcadExpInfo AS Latest ON loginInfo.ApplicantID = Latest.ApplicantID INNER JOIN dbo.Experience AS Exper ON loginInfo.ApplicantID = Exper.ApplicantID
    WHERE 1=1'

    SET @GROUPBY = 'GROUP BY loginInfo.ApplicantID, Personal.FirstName, Personal.LastName, Personal.Nationality, Job.PositionType, 
                                  Job.InterestedArea, loginInfo.ApplicantStatus, Latest.HighestDegree, Latest.CompletionDate, 
                                  Latest.LatestJobTitle, Latest.LatestCompanyIndustry, Latest.StartDate, Latest.EndDate

            ORDER BY ApplicantID DESC'

            EXEC(@SQL+@WHERE+@GROUPBY)
```

I Keep getting an error

```
Error: The multi-part identifier "dbo.LatestAcadExpInf" could not be bound. The multi-part identifier "dbo.Experience.StartDate" could not be bound. The multi-part identifier "dbo.Experience.EndDate" could not be bound
```

Comment: Have you heard of table aliases?  They would really simplify your query.  The error suggests that the tables and columns do not exist.

Comment: ok just did use aliases.. any other suggestions ?

Comment: Fix the column references so they refer to existing tables and columns.

Comment: PRINT out your SQL and try to run that - it will help you debug where in your string the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Weird, all i had to do was place the columns inside []..

Thanks to Whisk https://stackoverflow.com/a/206645/6240803