# Dynamic Where with dynamic Group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to have a query that given a `@given_case` it will return a table filtering and grouping the information given the case.

What I tried is

```
DECLARE @given_case nvarchar(50) = 'branch'

SELECT 
    CASE  @given_case 
            WHEN 'branch' THEN fk_branch
            WHEN 'department' THEN fk_department
    END as xxx,
    CASE  @given_case 
            WHEN 'branch' THEN COUNT(fk_branch)
            WHEN 'department' THEN COUNT(fk_department)
    END as xxxx,
    
    COUNT(fk_branch)
FROM dsv_global.staff
WHERE
(
    (
        @given_case = 'branch' 
        AND email LIKE 'a%'
    )
    OR
    (
        @given_case = 'department' 
        AND email LIKE 'b%'
    )
)
GROUP BY 

    CASE  @given_case 
        WHEN 'branch' THEN fk_branch
        WHEN 'department' THEN fk_department
END
```

And it works perfectly fine, but when I try to add more columns to the group by statement:

```
.
.
.
GROUP BY 

    CASE  @given_case 
        WHEN 'branch' THEN fk_branch, fk_staff
        WHEN 'department' THEN fk_department, fk_staff
END
```

I get the error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 65
> Incorrect syntax near ','.

I found someone who was trying to do something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37099915/sql-dynamic-where-and-group-by)

What they are doing is they store the `where` and the `group by` clauses in strings & then they run

```
EXCEC (@query + @where + @groupby)
```

This solution seems to work, but I don't want to do that because I think the query might become hard to maintain.

Are there any other options?

Comment: Not only is an `exec (@query + @where + @groupby)` harder to maintain, it is also dynamic SQL, which makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection.  You need to put the comma after the case statement, not inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case statement can only return a single column/value, not a tuple. Because `fk_staff` is common to both your groupings, though, you can simply do this...

```sql
GROUP BY 

    CASE  @given_case 
        WHEN 'branch' THEN fk_branch
        WHEN 'department' THEN fk_department
    END, fk_staff
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to separate out each possibility with is own `case` expression:

```
GROUP BY (CASE @given_case WHEN 'branch' THEN fk_branch END)
         (CASE @given_case WHEN 'department' THEN fk_department END),
         fk_staff
```

The reason is that a `CASE` expression returns a single expression -- with a single type.  The type of the expression is determined when the query is compiled -- and you might find that adding a new column results in a type conversion error.

With separate `CASE` expressions, there is no issue.  Each expression corresponds to a single column.