# Error message "The multi part identifier could not be bound"

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

My code is:

```
  ,CASE WHEN ResidenceInd = 1 THEN 'Residence' ELSE  'Day' END AS ClassType
  ,sc.Score
  ,'1' AS IsLP
  ,IncludeInGraph
  ,LessonOrder
FROM (
  SELECT
    sc.SchoolId
    ,sc.StudentId
    ,sc.DSTempSetColCalcId
    ,dcal.CalcType
    ,hdr.LessonPlanId
    ,hdr.StdtClassId
    ,Cls.ResidenceInd
    ,dcal.IncludeInGraph
    ,DHDR.LessonOrder
  FROM StdtSessColScore sc
    INNER JOIN DSTempSetColCalc dcal
      ON dcal.DSTempSetColCalcId = sc.DSTempSetColCalcId
    INNER JOIN StdtSessionHdr hdr
      ON hdr.StdtSessionHdrId=sc.StdtSessionHdrId
    INNER JOIN Class Cls 
      ON Cls.ClassId=hdr.StdtClassId 
    INNER JOIN DSTempHdr DHDR 
      ON DHDR.DSTempHdrId=hdr.DSTempHdrId
  WHERE 
   hdr.IOAInd='N' 
   AND hdr.SessMissTrailStus ='N' 
   AND hdr.SessionStatusCd='S' 
   AND (SELECT StatusId 
        FROM DSTempHdr DS 
        WHERE DS.DSTempHdrId = hdr.DSTempHdrId)
        <>
        (SELECT LookupId 
        FROM LookUp 
        WHERE LookupType = 'TemplateStatus' 
         AND LookupName='Deleted') 
  GROUP BY 
    DHDR.LessonOrder
    ,sc.SchoolId
    ,sc.StudentId
    ,sc.DSTempSetColCalcId
    ,dcal.CalcType
    ,hdr.LessonPlanId
    ,hdr.StdtClassId
    ,Cls.ResidenceInd
    ,dcal.IncludeInGraph
  ) AS StdCalcs
  ,ReportPeriod
WHERE 
  StdCalcs.StudentId=1240 
  AND CONVERT(DATE,'2016/01/02') <= CONVERT(DATE,ReportPeriod.PeriodDate)
  AND CONVERT(DATE,ReportPeriod.PeriodDate) <= CONVERT(DATE,'2016/12/28')
  AND sc.SchoolId = StdCalcs.SchoolId 
  AND sc.StudentId = StdCalcs.StudentId
  AND sc.DSTempSetColCalcId = StdCalcs.DSTempSetColCalcId
  AND CONVERT(DATE, Hdr.EndTs) = CONVERT(DATE, ReportPeriod.PeriodDate)
  AND Hdr.LessonPlanId = StdCalcs.LessonPlanId
  AND dcal.CalcType = StdCalcs.CalcType 
  AND Hdr.StdtClassId = StdCalcs.StdtClassId
  AND Hdr.IOAInd = 'N' AND Hdr.SessMissTrailStus ='N' 
  AND Hdr.SessionStatusCd = 'S' 
  AND sc.Score >= 0 
  AND Hdr.IsMaintanace = 0
GROUP BY
```

Code continues...

I'm getting a error :

> multipart identifier sc.SchoolId,sc.StudentId,sc.DSTempSetColCalcId,Hdr.EndTs,Hdr.LessonPlanId,dcal.CalcType,Hdr.StdtClassId,Hdr.IOAInd,Hdr.SessMissTrailStus,Hdr.SessionStatusCd,sc.ScoreHdr.IsMaintanace could not be bound.

actually how can we resolve it.. i was trying to add sc.score and

```
AND sc.SchoolId = StdCalcs.SchoolId 
AND sc.StudentId = StdCalcs.StudentId
AND sc.DSTempSetColCalcId = StdCalcs.DSTempSetColCalcId 
AND CONVERT(DATE, Hdr.EndTs) = CONVERT(DATE, ReportPeriod.PeriodDate)
AND Hdr.LessonPlanId=StdCalcs.LessonPlanId 
AND dcal.CalcType = StdCalcs.CalcType 
AND Hdr.StdtClassId = StdCalcs.StdtClassId
AND Hdr.IOAInd = 'N' AND Hdr.SessMissTrailStus = 'N'
AND Hdr.SessionStatusCd = 'S' 
AND sc.Score >= 0 
AND Hdr.IsMaintanace=0
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206558/what-is-a-multi-part-identifier-and-why-cant-it-be-bound . There's a good chance it's a typo. If you formatted your code better it might be easier to find. I'll re-format it to help you.

Comment: oh ok you over-wrote my formatting improvements. That's kind of frustrating...

Comment: You can't use inner query aliases (`sc`) in outer query.

Comment: sorry..just by mistake. how can i undo that @ADyson

Comment: @Binto, add full error message to your question.

Comment: @Binto just undo your edit. It should go back to my version I think. Then whatever you were meaning to change,  change it on top of the formatted version

Comment: And Arvo is right, you can't reference an alias from a subquery in an outer query.

Comment: It's not `sc` anymore outside of subquery - it's `StdCalcs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the comment in code below. If you get your data from a subquery as table, you cant use the internal table aliases of subquery but have to use the alias you give it as table.

```
CASE WHEN ResidenceInd=1 THEN 'Residence' ELSE  'Day' END AS ClassType
      ,StdCalcs.Score --here was the wrong table-alias
      ,'1' AS IsLP
      ,IncludeInGraph
      ,LessonOrder
      FROM (
      SELECT
      sc.SchoolId
      ,sc.StudentId
      ,sc.DSTempSetColCalcId
      ,dcal.CalcType
      ,hdr.LessonPlanId
      ,hdr.StdtClassId
      ,Cls.ResidenceInd
      ,dcal.IncludeInGraph
      ,DHDR.LessonOrder
      FROM StdtSessColScore  sc
      INNER JOIN DSTempSetColCalc dcal
      ON dcal.DSTempSetColCalcId = sc.DSTempSetColCalcId
      INNER JOIN StdtSessionHdr hdr
      ON hdr.StdtSessionHdrId=sc.StdtSessionHdrId
      INNER JOIN Class Cls ON Cls.ClassId=hdr.StdtClassId 
      INNER JOIN DSTempHdr DHDR ON DHDR.DSTempHdrId=hdr.DSTempHdrId
      WHERE hdr.IOAInd='N' AND hdr.SessMissTrailStus ='N' AND hdr.SessionStatusCd='S' AND (SELECT StatusId FROM DSTempHdr 
      DS WHERE DS.DSTempHdrId=hdr.DSTempHdrId)<>(SELECT LookupId FROM LookUp WHERE LookupType='TemplateStatus' AND LookupName='Deleted') 
      GROUP BY 
      DHDR.LessonOrder
      ,sc.SchoolId
      ,sc.StudentId
      ,sc.DSTempSetColCalcId
      ,dcal.CalcType
      ,hdr.LessonPlanId
      ,hdr.StdtClassId
      ,Cls.ResidenceInd
      ,dcal.IncludeInGraph
      ) AS StdCalcs
      ,ReportPeriod
      WHERE StdCalcs.StudentId=1240 AND CONVERT(DATE,'2016/01/02') <= CONVERT(DATE,ReportPeriod.PeriodDate) AND
      CONVERT(DATE,ReportPeriod.PeriodDate) <= CONVERT(DATE,'2016/12/28') and sc.SchoolId=StdCalcs.SchoolId AND sc.StudentId=StdCalcs.StudentId
      AND sc.DSTempSetColCalcId=StdCalcs.DSTempSetColCalcId AND CONVERT(DATE,Hdr.EndTs)=CONVERT(DATE,ReportPeriod.PeriodDate)
      AND Hdr.LessonPlanId=StdCalcs.LessonPlanId AND dcal.CalcType=StdCalcs.CalcType AND Hdr.StdtClassId=StdCalcs.StdtClassId
      AND Hdr.IOAInd='N' AND Hdr.SessMissTrailStus ='N' AND Hdr.SessionStatusCd='S' AND sc.Score>=0 AND Hdr.IsMaintanace=0
      GROUP BY
```

Comment: @Nițu Alexandru: basing on your "answer" below, maybe you're missing the code is not mine, i just fixed the error and edited the author's code adding a comment. So, calm down your hormones :)

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer!** It's just an advise on how to structure your query to better understand it. I advise you to spent more time on how to beauty your code. You will spent less time in the future on debug and understand what your code is doing. Here is your code:

```
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN ResidenceInd = 1 THEN 'Residence' 
            ELSE 'Day' 
        END AS ClassType
    ,StdCalcs.Score --here was the wrong table-alias
    ,'1' AS IsLP
    ,IncludeInGraph
    ,LessonOrder
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        sc.SchoolId
        ,sc.StudentId
        ,sc.DSTempSetColCalcId
        ,dcal.CalcType
        ,hdr.LessonPlanId
        ,hdr.StdtClassId
        ,Cls.ResidenceInd
        ,dcal.IncludeInGraph
        ,DHDR.LessonOrder
    FROM StdtSessColScore AS sc INNER JOIN 
        DSTempSetColCalc AS dcal ON dcal.DSTempSetColCalcId = sc.DSTempSetColCalcId INNER JOIN 
        StdtSessionHdr AS hdr ON hdr.StdtSessionHdrId = sc.StdtSessionHdrId INNER JOIN 
        Class AS Cls ON Cls.ClassId = hdr.StdtClassId INNER JOIN 
        DSTempHdr AS DHDR ON DHDR.DSTempHdrId = hdr.DSTempHdrId
    WHERE hdr.IOAInd = 'N' AND 
        hdr.SessMissTrailStus = 'N' AND 
        hdr.SessionStatusCd = 'S' AND 
        (
            SELECT StatusId 
            FROM DSTempHdr DS 
            WHERE DS.DSTempHdrId = hdr.DSTempHdrId
        ) <> 
        (
            SELECT LookupId 
            FROM LookUp 
            WHERE LookupType = 'TemplateStatus' AND 
                LookupName = 'Deleted'
        )
    GROUP BY DHDR.LessonOrder
        ,sc.SchoolId
        ,sc.StudentId
        ,sc.DSTempSetColCalcId
        ,dcal.CalcType
        ,hdr.LessonPlanId
        ,hdr.StdtClassId
        ,Cls.ResidenceInd
        ,dcal.IncludeInGraph
) AS StdCalcs,
    ReportPeriod
WHERE StdCalcs.StudentId = 1240 AND 
    CONVERT(DATE, '2016/01/02') <= CONVERT(DATE, ReportPeriod.PeriodDate) AND
    CONVERT(DATE, ReportPeriod.PeriodDate) <= CONVERT(DATE, '2016/12/28') AND 
    sc.SchoolId = StdCalcs.SchoolId AND 
    sc.StudentId = StdCalcs.StudentId AND 
    sc.DSTempSetColCalcId=StdCalcs.DSTempSetColCalcId AND 
    CONVERT(DATE, Hdr.EndTs) = CONVERT(DATE, ReportPeriod.PeriodDate) AND 
    Hdr.LessonPlanId=StdCalcs.LessonPlanId AND 
    dcal.CalcType = StdCalcs.CalcType AND 
    Hdr.StdtClassId = StdCalcs.StdtClassId AND 
    Hdr.IOAInd = 'N' AND 
    Hdr.SessMissTrailStus = 'N' AND 
    Hdr.SessionStatusCd = 'S' AND 
    sc.Score >= 0 AND 
    Hdr.IsMaintanace = 0
GROUP BY
```

In the **select, group by, order by** clauses: try to place each column on it's own row.

In the **form** clause: place each table and the on from the joins on a row.

In the **where** clause: place each condition on a row. Place AND or OR an the beginning or at the end.

**Everywhere**: write a white space before equality sign and after. You can see the left and the right member easier.