# How can I structure a trigger to record previous values when updated?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

EDIT: I'm working on SQL Server 2012

I'm working on a project in which two columns in a table need to have their data recorded whenever they are updated. So for it to work, when someone decides to update the address or zipcode and save it, an audit table needs to record the previous value that was in the column ***before*** it was updated.

I already made a start by setting up an audit table to hold the required data

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_Audit
(
Cust_UpdateID int IDENTITY (1,1),
Cust_User char (8),
Cust_Update_Date date,
Cust_ID int, 
CustomerAddresss nvarchar (255),
CustomerZipCode nvarchar (255),

CONSTRAINT [pk_Cust_UpdateID] PRIMARY KEY (Cust_UpdateID)

)
```

The only issue I'm facing is establishing an actual trigger query to fill the audit table with the required data from the customer table. I have been told an AFTER UPDATE trigger would be ideal, but I have NO idea how to set this up properly and take the data I need and populate the audit table itself.

Can someone recommend and show me how to set up a trigger that can do what I'm looking to do?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using (which is presumably SQL Server based on the syntax).

Comment: Does your original table contain the same columns `Cust_ID`, `CustomerAddress`, and `CustomerZipCode`? And is the name of your original table `Customer`?

Comment: The original table contains those 3 columns and yes it is called Customer

Comment: This is the best I've seen for a one size fits all solution to what you are trying to do: [Quick And Easy Audit Tables - Dave Britten](http://dave.brittens.org/blog/quick-and-easy-audit-tables.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "deleted" and "inserted" tables in your trigger: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300(v=sql.110).aspx

```
CREATE TRIGGER Customer_update_trig ON Customer
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Customer_Audit (Cust_User, Cust_Update_Date, Cust_ID, CustomerAddresss, CustomerZipCode)
  SELECT d.Cust_User,
    d.Cust_Update_Date,
    d.Cust_ID,
    d.CustomerAddresss, --sic
    d.CustomerZipCode
  FROM deleted d
END

-- OR for auto generated user and timestamp

CREATE TRIGGER Customer_update_trig ON Customer
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Customer_Audit (Cust_User, Cust_Update_Date, Cust_ID, CustomerAddresss, CustomerZipCode)
  SELECT CURRENT_USER,
    GETDATE(),
    d.Cust_ID,
    d.CustomerAddresss, --sic
    d.CustomerZipCode
  FROM deleted d
END
```

Of course, you'll want to put your schema name in there too (or 'dbo' if using the default). And double-check the column names that they match your original table.

For your audit strategy, you'll want to decide if you only want to record after an update, or eagerly record the original insert also.

Another thing for `SELECT` optimization from your audit table, you can have much more efficient `WHERE` clauses if you have a `Cust_Record_Start_Time` and `Cust_Record_End_Time` to give a range for when the record was valid. It is much easier to query on a point in time with that data.

I don't have SQL Server anymore, so I wasn't able to test the syntax, but the concept should be there.

Additionally, if adding this trigger adds too much time to your UPDATE statements, you can look into Service Broker: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893(v=sql.110).aspx

It allows for async guaranteed "messages" that could update your audit table in very near real time.

Comment: Although this answers OP's question: a) this fits better as a comment. b) link-only answers should include relevant text in the body and c) in general, this is a low-quality question and shouldn't be answerd for the sake of quality of the site

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll try to get some more info from the OP and add a relevant example.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I'm a bit confused on the bit after the INSERT INTO section.

Comment: What does the SELECT d.Cust_user, d.Cust_update_date etc mean?

Comment: Also I forgot to mention some of the fields would be automatically added, they wouldn't be part of the customer table. Like the Cust_user and the Cust_update_date would be automatically generated

Comment: What will automatically generate the Cust_user? For the Cust_update_date, you can use `GETDATE()` - although it would be good to have that field on your original table also.  In the trigger, SQL Server provides two "tables" that you can perform queries on - "inserted" (new data) and "deleted" (old data) - all this code is doing is selecting records from the "deleted" table and using the results to INSERT into your audit table. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263(v=sql.105).aspx#code-snippet-4

Comment: If you want the SQL Server user, then you can use `CURRENT_USER`

Comment: @marksiemers I'm still facing issues with the trigger query, I keep getting error messages back referring that the three columns (CustomerID, CustomerAddress and CustomerZipCode) from the deleted table, it says that these three multi-part identifiers cannot be bound

Comment: Double-check your column names. In your original `Customer` table, are the column names just `ID`, `Address`, and `ZipCode`? If so, don't use `d.CustomerID` - just `d.ID`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206558/what-is-a-multi-part-identifier-and-why-cant-it-be-bound

Comment: @marksiemers But that's the thing though, those columns do match the columns in the Customer table. So i don't understand why it keeps generating the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference both the old and new values within the trigger, allowing you to reference the desired data and import it into the audit table.  It's unclear from your description exactly what data is being taken from the Customer table, so I've set it up with the assumption that all of the audit fields have equivalent fields in the Customer table, except for the Cust_UpdateID.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_audit_table
    AFTER UPDATE
    ON Customer
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO Customer_Audit(Cust_User, Cust_ID, Cust_Update_Date, CustomerAddress, CustomerZipCode)
      VALUES (OLD.Cust_User, OLD.Cust_ID, OLD.Cust_Update_date, OLD.CustomerAddress, OLD.CustomerZipCode)
    END
```

Note: within the trigger OLD is a reference to the row before the changes were made, and NEW would be a reference to the row after the changes were made.

Comment: Cust_User, Cust_Update_Date are fields that should be automatically generated from the trigger. I should have specified that , I'm sorry. How can I set it up in the table to automatically generate those fields, but take the other fields from the Customer table.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting these fields to track?  You can set the value of those fields to whatever you want in the trigger, I'm just unclear what data you're actually trying to store in these columns.

Comment: I'm only trying to store the ID, Address and Zipcode from the Customer table whenever it's updated. That's the whole point of the trigger, it's meant to take those values and store them so it keeps a record of them. whenever they're updated.

Comment: Still not sure what data you're wanting to be generated for the Cust_User and Cust_Update_Date fields.  If Cust_Update_Date is just the timestamp for when the audit record is created, I'd just make that column have the default value of the current timestamp instead of setting it in the trigger.  I'm unclear what data is meant to be stored in the Cust_User column.