# SQL Server attempt to retrieve name from foreign key tables failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have to design a database for a book store and I have constructed a table called 'Reviews' that references foreign keys belonging to the Costumer table and Book table. My problem is that I seem to be unable to make a join command that will display results for the Names of all books that currently have reviews.

```
    create database Bookorama

    use Bookorama


    --Book table

    create table Book
    ( 
    bookID int identity(1,1),
    bookName varchar(50) unique,
    price smallmoney,
    primary key (bookID)
    );

    --Customer table
    create table Customer
    (
    custID int not null identity (1,1),
    cName varchar(50),
    cemid varchar(50),
    primary key (custID)
    );

    -- Order table

    create table Ordertable
    (
    orderID int identity(1,1),
    custID int not null,
    bookID int not null,
    primary key (orderID),
    foreign key (custid) references Customer(custid),
    foreign key (bookID) references Book(bookid)
    );

    create table Reviews
    (
    reviewID int identity (1,1) not null,
    custID int not null,
    bookID int not null,
    review varchar(50),
    primary key (reviewID),
    foreign key (custID) references Customer(custID),
    foreign key (bookID) references Book(bookID)
    )
```

When I attempt to display the names of books that currently have reviews:

```
    select Book.bookName from Book
    left outer join Book as BookswithReviews
    on (Book.bookID = Reviews.bookID);
```

The following code gives me the following error:

> The multi-part identifier "Reviews.bookID" could not be bound.

I'm just getting started with SQL so please excuse my incompetency, but every type of solution that I seem to have found gives me the same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a 'multi-part identifier' and why can't it be bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206558/what-is-a-multi-part-identifier-and-why-cant-it-be-bound)

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the BookReview table in the From/Join clause:

```
select Book.bookName from Book
    inner join Reviews 
        on (Book.bookID = Reviews.bookID);
```

No idea why you had 'Book as BooksWithReviews'.

Also, using an outer join will give you all books, with and without. Using an inner join gives only those with.

Comment: Thank you so much XD, yeah I was having difficulty understanding what and how things were being referanced, but what you said clarified everything.