# How to convert the data to array form in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have the following code and the datatable only contain one row. I wish to keep the all the data(the one row) value in array. Below is my code:

```
            SqlCommand cmdp = new SqlCommand("SELECT [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7].[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31],[32],[33],[34],[35],[36],[37],[38],[39],[40],[41],[42],[43],[44],[45],[46],[47],[48],[49],[50],[51],[52],[53],[54],[55],[56],[57],[58],[59],[60],[61],[62],[63],[64],[65],[66],[67],[68],[69],[70],[71],[72],[73],[74],[75],[76],[77],[78] from [Seatlist] where (([FlightNo] = @FN) AND ([Origin] = @Ori) AND ([Destination] = @Des) AND ([DepartureTimeDay] = @Dep) AND ( [DepartureTimeMonths] = @Dem) AND ( [DepartureTimeYears] = @Dey) AND ( [DepartureTime] = @Det))", con);
            cmdp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Seatlist", SeatNo.Text);
            cmdp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", FlightNo.Text);
            cmdp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ori", Origin.Text);
            cmdp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Des", Destination.Text);
            cmdp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dep", DepartDay.Text);
            cmdp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dem", DepartMonth.Text);
            cmdp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dey", DepartureTimeYears.Text);
            cmdp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Det", DepartureTime.Text);
            DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
            dtable.Load(cmdp.ExecuteReader());
            DataRow[] array = dtable.AsEnumerable().Take(1).ToArray();
            object[] array1 = array[0].ItemArray;
            int[] array2 = Array.ConvertAll(array1, (p => Convert.ToInt32(p)));
```

But I get the following error:

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The multi-part identifier "7.8" could not be bound.
```

Comment: The `[7].[8]` should probably be `[7],[8]`. The `.` in SQL is a multipart identifier - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206558/what-is-a-multi-part-identifier-and-why-cant-it-be-bound

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a 'multi-part identifier' and why can't it be bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206558/what-is-a-multi-part-identifier-and-why-cant-it-be-bound)

Comment: [Can  we stop using AddWithValue already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work fine now ...

```
 SqlCommand cmdp = new SqlCommand("SELECT [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31],[32],[33],[34],[35],[36],[37],[38],[39],[40],[41],[42],[43],[44],[45],[46],[47],[48],[49],[50],[51],[52],[53],[54],[55],[56],[57],[58],[59],[60],[61],[62],[63],[64],[65],[66],[67],[68],[69],[70],[71],[72],[73],[74],[75],[76],[77],[78] from [Seatlist] where (([FlightNo] = @FN) AND ([Origin] = @Ori) AND ([Destination] = @Des) AND ([DepartureTimeDay] = @Dep) AND ( [DepartureTimeMonths] = @Dem) AND ( [DepartureTimeYears] = @Dey) AND ( [DepartureTime] = @Det))", con);
                cmdp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Seatlist", SeatNo.Text);
                cmdp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", FlightNo.Text);
                cmdp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ori", Origin.Text);
                cmdp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Des", Destination.Text);
                cmdp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dep", DepartDay.Text);
                cmdp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dem", DepartMonth.Text);
                cmdp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dey", DepartureTimeYears.Text);
                cmdp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Det", DepartureTime.Text);
                DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
                dtable.Load(cmdp.ExecuteReader());
                DataRow[] array = dtable.AsEnumerable().Take(1).ToArray();
                object[] array1 = array[0].ItemArray;
                int[] array2 = Array.ConvertAll(array1, (p => Convert.ToInt32(p)));
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Kami pointed out your Code is pretty much fine, but you got a `[7].[8]` instead of `[7],[8]` at char 66-73