# Multi part identifier could not be bound for inserting query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with Patient_id, surgery_dt(Table1). I need to insert all the Weight, Height details from (Table2) to (Table3) where the Table2.date falls before and after 6 months of surgery_dt.

I share with you the code I tried.  but it returns : 
"The multi-part identifier "b.Sur_dt" could not be bound."

Kindly suggest some ideas to resolve the query. 
Thanks in advance!

```
    select a.patient_id,a.Record_Date,a.Height,a.Weight,a.Waist,a.hip into Table3 from Table2 a
where a.Record_Date between b.Sur_dt-180 and b.Sur_dt+180 and a.Patient_id in (select b.Patient_id from Table1 b where a.patient_id = b.patient_id)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a 'multi-part identifier' and why can't it be bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206558/what-is-a-multi-part-identifier-and-why-cant-it-be-bound)

Comment: The table alias of `b` is not accessible in your main `SELECT` query. since the `WHERE IN()` is executed as a subquery, you would need to use a `JOIN` to establish the alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below - using `JOIN`

```
select a.patient_id,a.Record_Date,a.Height,a.Weight,a.Waist,a.hip into Table3 
from Table2 a inner join Table1 b on a.patient_id = b.patient_id
where a.Record_Date between b.Sur_dt-180 and b.Sur_dt+180
```