# Acumatica multi part identifier could not be bound

Tags: c#, acumatica

I get this error on my customize pop up grid "multi part identifier could not be bound"

i have a projection

```
    [PXProjection(typeof(Select2<InventoryItem,
    LeftJoin<INLotSerialStatus, On<INLotSerialStatus.FK.InventoryItem>,
    LeftJoin<INLocation, On<INLotSerialStatus.locationID, Equal<INLocation.locationID>>,
    LeftJoin<INSubItem, On<INLotSerialStatus.FK.SubItem>,
    LeftJoin<INSite, On<INLotSerialStatus.FK.Site>,
    LeftJoin<INItemXRef,
        On2<INItemXRef.FK.InventoryItem, And<INItemXRef.alternateType, Equal<INAlternateType.barcode>,
        And2<Where<INItemXRef.subItemID, Equal<INLotSerialStatus.subItemID>, Or<INLotSerialStatus.subItemID, IsNull>>,
        And<CurrentValue<AllocationSerialStatusFilter.barCode>, IsNotNull>>>>,
    LeftJoin<INTranSplit,
        On<INTranSplit.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>,
        And<INTranSplit.subItemID, Equal<INLotSerialStatus.subItemID>,
        And<INTranSplit.invtMult, Equal<CS.short1>,
        And<INTranSplit.lotSerialNbr, Equal<INLotSerialStatus.lotSerialNbr>>>>>,
    LeftJoin<BAccount,
        On<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<INTranSplitExt.usrConsignmentVendor>>,
    LeftJoin<PO.POReceiptLineSplit,
            On<PO.POReceiptLineSplit.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>,
            And<PO.POReceiptLineSplit.subItemID, Equal<INLotSerialStatus.subItemID>,
            And<PO.POReceiptLineSplit.invtMult, Equal<CS.short1>,
            And<PO.POReceiptLineSplit.lotSerialNbr, Equal<INLotSerialStatus.lotSerialNbr>>>>>,
    LeftJoin<PO.POReceiptLine,
        On<PO.POReceiptLine.receiptType, Equal<PO.POReceiptLineSplit.receiptType>,
        And<PO.POReceiptLine.receiptNbr, Equal<PO.POReceiptLineSplit.receiptNbr>,
        And<PO.POReceiptLine.lineNbr, Equal<PO.POReceiptLineSplit.lineNbr>>>>,
    LeftJoin<PO.POReceipt,
        On<PO.POReceipt.receiptType, Equal<PO.POReceiptLine.receiptType>,
            And<PO.POReceipt.receiptNbr, Equal<PO.POReceiptLine.receiptNbr>>>,
    LeftJoin<AP.Vendor, On<AP.Vendor.bAccountID, Equal<PO.POReceipt.vendorID>>
        >>>>>>>>>>>,
    Where2<CurrentMatch<InventoryItem, AccessInfo.userName>,
    And2<Where<INLotSerialStatus.siteID, IsNull, Or<INSite.branchID, IsNotNull,
    And2<CurrentMatch<INSite, AccessInfo.userName>,
    And<Where2<FeatureInstalled<CS.FeaturesSet.interBranch>, Or<SameOrganizationBranch<INSite.branchID, Current<SO.SOOrder.branchID>>>>>>>>,
    And2<Where<INLotSerialStatus.subItemID, IsNull, Or<CurrentMatch<INSubItem, AccessInfo.userName>>>,
    And<INLotSerialStatus.qtyAvail, Greater<CS.decimal0>,
    And2<Where<CurrentValue<AllocationSerialStatusFilter.siteID>, IsNull, Or<INLotSerialStatus.siteID, Equal<CurrentValue<AllocationSerialStatusFilter.siteID>>>>,
    And2<Where<CurrentValue<AllocationSerialStatusFilter.inventoryID>, IsNull, Or<INLotSerialStatus.inventoryID, Equal<CurrentValue<AllocationSerialStatusFilter.inventoryID>>>>,
    And2<Where<CurrentValue<AllocationSerialStatusFilter.locationID>, IsNull, Or<INLotSerialStatus.locationID, Equal<CurrentValue<AllocationSerialStatusFilter.locationID>>>>,
    And2<Where<CurrentValue<AllocationSerialStatusFilter.fromDate>, IsNull, Or<INLotSerialStatus.receiptDate, GreaterEqual<CurrentValue<AllocationSerialStatusFilter.fromDate>>>>,
    And2<Where<CurrentValue<AllocationSerialStatusFilter.toDate>, IsNull, Or<INLotSerialStatus.receiptDate, LessEqual<CurrentValue<AllocationSerialStatusFilter.toDate>>>>,
    And<InventoryItem.stkItem, Equal<CS.boolTrue>,
    And<InventoryItem.isTemplate, Equal<False>,
    And<InventoryItem.itemStatus, NotIn3<InventoryItemStatus.unknown, InventoryItemStatus.inactive, InventoryItemStatus.markedForDeletion>>>>>>>>>>>>>>), Persistent = false)]
```

Everything works fine and shows up on my grid but when i try to filter

```
        #region VendorName

    public abstract class vendorName : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<vendorName> { }
    [PXDBString(BqlField = typeof(AP.Vendor.acctName))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Vendor Name")]
    public virtual string VendorName { get; set; }

        #region ConsignmentVendor
    public abstract class consignmentVendor : BqlType<IBqlString, string>.Field<consignmentVendor> { }
    [PXDBString(BqlField = typeof(BAccount.acctName))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Consignment Vendor")]
    public virtual string ConsignmentVendor { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region POReceiptNbr
    public abstract class pOReceiptNbr : BqlType<IBqlString, string>.Field<pOReceiptNbr> { }
    [PXDBString(15, IsUnicode = true, BqlField = typeof(PO.POReceipt.receiptNbr))]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<PO.POReceipt.receiptNbr>))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "PO Receipt Nbr.")]
    public virtual string POReceiptNbr { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region INventoryNbr
    public abstract class inventoryNbr : BqlType<IBqlString, string>.Field<inventoryNbr> { }
    [PXDBString(15, IsUnicode = true, BqlField = typeof(INTranSplit.refNbr))]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<INTranSplit.refNbr>))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Inventory Receipt Nbr.")]
    public virtual string InventoryNbr { get; set; }
    #endregion
```

Like for example filter header for is empty filter i tried many ways on getting the cd out of id but all is failing maybe if there is another way to get the cd with vendorid
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, notice that DAC `AllocationSerialStatusFilter` in the `Where` clause is not in the `Select` or `Join` clauses.

The `CurrentValue` BQL operator could refer to a DAC which is in the Select/Join clause.

```
[PXProjection(typeof(Select<Vendor, 
                     Where<Vendor.payToVendorID, Equal<CurrentValue<Vendor.bAccountID>>>>))]
```

If it is not, make sure `Current` value is available in caches somewhere.

```
public PXFilter<Vendor> CurrentVendor;
```

For the multi-part error, check if the joins resolves to a 1 to 1 relationship.

```
LeftJoin<BAccount, On<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<INTranSplitExt.usrConsignmentVendor>>
```

You are joining `BAccount` with `INTranSplit`. Check if there is only one BAcccount tied to one INTranSplit.

```
LeftJoin<INTranSplit,
    On<INTranSplit.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>,
    And<INTranSplit.subItemID, Equal<INLotSerialStatus.subItemID>,
    And<INTranSplit.invtMult, Equal<CS.short1>,
    And<INTranSplit.lotSerialNbr, Equal<INLotSerialStatus.lotSerialNbr>>>>>,
```

Comment: By the way, this is likely a Join error occurring at DB level : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206558/what-is-a-multi-part-identifier-and-why-cant-it-be-bound